# Why doesn't the load event trigger when the back/forward button is clicked, causing the loader to remain visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that includes a loader, and I'm using JavaScript to control when it should be displayed and hidden. The loader is initially displayed on page load using the showLoader function, and it should also be displayed when the user navigates away from the page using the back/forward buttons.

To handle the back/forward button navigation, I'm using the **beforeunload** event listener to call the shouldShowLoader function. This function checks if the event is cancelable and then schedules the showLoader function to run after a short delay (50 milliseconds).
Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const loaderWrapper = document.querySelector(".loader-wrapper");

  function showLoader() {
    loaderWrapper.classList.remove("hidden");
  }

  function hideLoader() {
    loaderWrapper.classList.add("hidden");
  }

  function shouldShowLoader(event) {
    const cancelable = event.cancelable;
    if (isValid(cancelable)) {
      setTimeout(showLoader, 50);
    }
  }

  function isValid(formElement) {
    return formElement !== null;
  }

  // Show the loader initially
  showLoader();

  window.addEventListener("load", hideLoader);
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", shouldShowLoader);
});
```

It was working fine in my browser, but for some browsers, while clicking the back/forward button **beforeunload**, the event call and show loader will be called, and my loader will remain visible. **load** event will not call.
I have tried to use **popstate **event, but still it is a visible loader.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function () {
    if (history.state === null) {
      // Hide the loader
      hideLoader();
    }
  });
```

I want to solve this issue. How to fix it Any insights or suggestions on how to correctly trigger the loader when using the back and forward buttons would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The navigation process aborts all the pending AJAX calls, timers etc. You can't do anything asynchronous in `beforeunload` handler.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with beforeunload - instead it's `// Show the loader initially` which loads the load when the browsed-to-page is loading then the popstate is not firing to hide it.  Remove all your `beforeunload` code to see this.

Comment: Some browsers will no use `bfcache` instead of `popstate` - so you need to handle both.  https://web.dev/bfcache/